# Fabrik calc field and outstanding days

Tags: fabrik

I'm building internal erp based on joomla. main component for forms, database etc is Fabrik. At moment it's works great but I stuck on one field what I have problem to make working on way as I would like to.
I have a form to edit previously entred data on another form. In this form one of field is Outstanding days. I use calc field type. Trouble is it's don't want to make required calculations.
my php code for this field is:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date_format({enquiries___due_date}, 'Y-m-d'));
$interval=date_diff($datetime1,$datetime2);
return $interval;
```

Comment: what's <code>{enquiries___due_date}</code> ? isn't it a variable? http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php, missing <code>$</code> ?

Comment: This is parms from fabrik, this is how you call elements to use

Answer (score 1):

The error was simple stupid mistake. I missing a qoute on {enquiries___due_date} when I place this in quote everything start working.